# drupal - jQuery, can't select any elements via jQuery

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have a form and I add a js file via drupal_add_js() in the init code of the module.

I see the first debug message, but I can't seem to select any items from the document. I just get the jQuery object returned.

But when I add the same line into the firebug, it works.

```
console.log('called => init()');
console.log(jQuery('#quiz-form').find('#edit-next'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by chance. The jQuery object was trying to find the selected object before the page was initialized.

I was thinking drupal_add_js in the init module was enough.

BUt I had to wrap the jquery code in the Dom Ready function as well... as we always are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to retrieve the value from your form element, try:

```
console.log(jQuery('#quiz-form').find('#edit-next').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the jQuery object as return is perfectly fine as methods like `find` actually return a jQuery object. You should check the length of the jQuery object that you are getting as return i.e. `console.log(jQuery('#quiz-form').find('#edit-next').length);`. If the length is zero, then of course the elements are not being found. In that case you should make sure that your JS code is being called after the DOM is ready i.e. you should either wrap your code with `jQuery(document).ready` or use Drupal behaviors.